# How to set "dots" loader when API loads a response in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, spinner, loader

I am in ionic 2 application ,i can add spinner on html page as `<ion-spinner name="dots"></ion-spinner>` but want to set "dots" Spinner during awaiting time of API response.

current response waiting loader code is :

```
 fnPresentLoading() {
     this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
     content: 'Please wait...'
     });
   this.loading.present();
```

anyone have idea ??
Currently it  showing default spinner .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `spinner` parameter and pass `'dots'` to it

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  spinner: 'dots',
  content: 'Please wait...'
});
```